# Why is PyCharm not displaying my txt files?

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm 4.0.5 - I can right-click and add a file with a name like "test.txt" and the file will show up in the project folder on the file system. The file does not appear in the Project window in PyCharm. Other projects on the same computer display .txt files within the project.

How do I get PyCharm to display .txt files in the Project window?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the settings under Settings | Editor | File Types | Ignore files and folders and make sure that none of the masks listed there match the text file that you're trying to add.